# Specifying unusual repository layouts in ~/.sbt/repositories file

Tags: scala, sbt

The sbt documentation covers the basic format of the repositories file. It seems to be mostly specified in the launcher documentation (for `sbt.boot.properties`) at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html:

```
[repositories]
  repo-name: URL, ivypattern
```

Which works fine for most repositories. Unfortunately, I have an unusually laid-out repository that I configure in sbt scala code by calling `Resolver.file.ivys(patternToIvies).artifacts(patternToArtifacts)`, where the two have slightly different locations.

Is there some way to achieve that flexibility in the `repositories` file? I'd rather not republish all the artifacts in the unusual repository to a more sanely structured one just yet.

Comment: As an aside, it was pretty hard to find a formal spec for that `repositories` file. It took me a while to find it in the launcher configuration section.

Comment: I think you cannot have it for local repository. But you can have different patterns for a repository accessed via URL. `customRepository: label ":" url [ ["," ivyPattern] ["," artifactPattern] [", mavenCompatible"] [", bootOnly"]]`. E.g. `custom: file://whatever, /pattern-to-ivies, /pattern-to-artifacts` where of course `pattern-to-ivies` and `pattern-to-artifacts` could be patterns. Would this help?

Comment: Oh, interesting! I didn't realize that was possible. Don't need to do it for the local repository. I'll try this out, thanks!